# Hibernate in parsing

Tags: hibernate

I created a hibernate program to insert date in to mysql got the following error:

```
problem parsing configurationcom\xml\hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
                 problem parsing configurationcom\xml\hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.candidjava.AddStudent.main(AddStudent.java:58)
```

Comment: The error seems to speak for itself, you have an error somewhere in your hibernate.cfg.xml. Try loading it in an editor that supports XML and you should see the error, otherwise you'd need to post it to get more help.

Comment: If you add your selected code that would be easy to answer to anyone..

Comment: I suggest you look at com.candidjava.AddStudent.main(AddStudent.java:58) and see what is causing NullPointerException. It is most likely undefined (or incorrectly defined) dependency.